# Kubernetes sharing a binary across nodes

Tags: kubernetes, volumes, mounted-volumes

Is there an alternative to sharing a jdbc driver across multiple pods spread over multiple nodes?  I am using a NFS share, however, in case I need to spin up a brand new node, I would need to perform an additional step of mounting the NFS share.  Configmaps will not work.  But I wish there is a mechanism where out of the box I can minimize these considerations.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Have you considered an init container that downloads the driver you want into an `emptyDir{}` volume before each pod starts? I assume you don't want to bake the driver into your image for some legitimate reason.

Comment: Wouldn't the init container need the driver to be available on the host machine?  Not sure how the init would help.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: The init container can do the job of downloading the driver from any remote location really - even git. Does your case even have a dependency on the host machine? Then in that case, you can have a daemonset that does the requisite things on the node as soon as it starts up.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: @sharman did initContainer solved your issue?